# Get data using the Date Range when 'WHERE NOT EXISTS' is used

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

From the table I need get data using the Date Range on the below query mentioned when **'WHERE NOT EXISTS'** is used in SQL Server.

```
declare @Start DATETIME, 
        @End DATETIME 

    Set @Start = '01/01/2020'
    Set @End  = '01/15/2020'

select A.request_id, A.order_id
       from table_a A
where not exists (select * from table_b B where B.request_id=A.request_id 
       and B.order_id=A.order_id)
and WHERE (provided_date between @Start and @End)
```

**need to include** `WHERE provided_date between @Start and @End`

When date range is applied, I need the data for the provided date range. How do I achieve this?
Please find the below table and expected output:

`**TABLE A**`

```
request_id|order_id|Provided_Date
10        |2567    |01/01/2020
20        |4784    |01/03/2020
30        |2578    |01/07/2020
40        |8432    |01/10/2020
50        |9032    |01/13/2020
```

`**TABLE B**`

```
request_id|order_id|Provided_Date
30        |2578    |01/07/2020
40        |8432    |01/10/2020
```

`**EXPECTED OUTPUT**`

```
request_id|order_id|Provided_Date
10        |2567    |01/01/2020
20        |4784    |01/03/2020
50        |9032    |01/13/2020
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain why you are using unsupported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Why have you tagged 2  versions of SQL Server that hit end of life years ago? Are you really using those versions? If so, you really should be prioritising using a more recent version.

Comment: As for the question, what did you try? Why *can't* you include the clause you show in the appropriate place in the`WHERE`s you have?

Comment: @Larnu  I'm using 2012 MSSQL version and included the clause now as how I used earlier and added example how the output is required

Comment: @DaleK I'm using 2012 version

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` from `and WHERE (provided_date between @Start and @End)`. It should just read `and  (provided_date between @Start and @End)`. And the `SELECT *` in your `NOT EXISTS` should be `SELECT 1` instead, as you don't need to return any of the columns in your test, and you definitely don't need to return all of them - you just need to know whether the row exists or not.

Comment: @KenWhite when I use `and  (provided_date between @Start and @End)` It gives me the whole data(1 year data present in DB) expect for the provided date range.

Comment: *" I'm using 2012 MSSQL version"* Then why tag [tag:sql-server-2005] and [tag:sql-server-2008]? Please do ensure you tag correctly; looking at your other questions I am sure this is not the first time you have been asked to do so.

Comment: Then use `WHERE (a.provided_date between @Start and @End)`. If the test is supposed to be part of the `NOT EXIStS`, then move it inside the parenthesis for that test and if needed change the `a` to `b` in the date clause.

Comment: @KenWhite That worked. Thanks!

Comment: @KenWhite The _select list_ in an `exists` query is a syntactic requirement, not semantic. Whether it is `*`, `42`, `NULL` or `1 / 0` the query optimizer will disregard it and the execution plan will be the same. My personal preference is to use [`42`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_is_42) as an indication that I thought about it and the value doesn't matter. Using `*` just to tweak the _NEVER USE SELECT *_ crowd is just as valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post a question,please share us  your table structure (CREATE TABLE …) and some sample data(INSERT INTO …)
along with your expected result. So that we’ll get a right direction and make some test.

Try:

```
declare @Start DATETIME, 
        @End DATETIME 

Set @Start = '01/01/2020'
Set @End  = '01/15/2020'

select request_id, order_id,Provided_Date
from table_a 
where request_id not in (select request_idfrom table_b )
      and provided_date between @Start and @End
```